# Delete and Put. Should they be used?

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, put

I am watching some videos on ASP.NET Web API and in the video they are using the "Delete" and "Put" command. I never actually used this before and always just used "Post" and "Get" when ever I just used regular ASP.NET MVC and jquery with ajax.

Seeing this is a MS video I wanted to check if that is standard practice to now use them or something MS just decided to do.

Comment: It's not ASP.NET MVC Web API, It's ASP.NET Web API. It has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/newsflash-asp-net-web-api-does-not-sit-on-top-of-asp-net-mvc-in-fact-it-does-not-sit-on-top-of-anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a standard practice for RESTful APIs.

REST utilizes HTTP Verbs and other existing features of HTTP protocol to provide a standardized, discoverable way of using your API.

You can learn more about REST here - http://www.restapitutorial.com/.

And more about HTTP verbs - http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: How about when your doing non REST? Should you still use them?

Comment: you don't have to do REST, to use HTTP Verbs. IF you choose to use them, you get the obvious benefits of having a standardized API - updates always happen with PUT, deletions with DELETE. The consumer of the API doesn't have to wonder or guess how he should form the request in order to perform these operations.

Comment: according to HTTP spec POST should create resources/submit something for processing, not deleting or updating resources. Of course nothing stops you from going against the HTTP spec and implement delete/update with POST, but why not just adhere to standards?